# mutiple arugment with date range in filter with object query set in django?

Tags: python, django

I'm passing multiple argument in a filter, but when I try to pass date range it's not working, and showing an error : I wrote the following code for that:

```
where_con = {}
for k in model_k_j:
    type_val = type(model_k_j[k])
    if type_val== dict:
        print "dictonary type"
        where_con[k] =  medical_home_last_visit__range=["2012-1-1","2013-11-21" ]
    else:
        col_name.append(k)
        where_con[k] =  model_k_j[k] 

# **where_con {unpack tuple}
print where_con
qs_new = model_obj.objects.filter(**where_con)
```

Can you suggest what is wrong in that?

Answer (score 1):

range should be a tuple of datetime objects not strings, check the reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#range

Comment: @@daveoncode: suppose i want to pass two filter , one is date range and another gender category

{colname_range[start,end],colname='m'}   how can do ?

since col_name and no of argument both are coming dynamically..

Comment: I don't understand your concerns… you can pass filters dynamically by unpacking a dictionary as you did in your example (Model.objects.filters(**filtersDictionary))

Comment: for model_field_dict in model_k_j[k]:
                            start= model_k_j[k][model_field_dict]
                            end= model_k_j[k][model_field_dict]
                            where_con[k] =  medical_home_last_visit__range=[start,end ]

here "medical_home_last_visit" is dynamic how to append with date range operator...